# EOFexception caused by empty file

Tags: java, file

I created a new file `roomChecker` which is empty. Now when I read it, it throws me an EOFException which is undesirable. Instead I want it to see that, if file is empty then it would run other two functions that are in `if(roomFeed.size() == 0)` condition. I could write this statement in EOFException catch clause; but that's not what I want to do because then every time when the file will be read and reaches end of file it will execute those functions. Instead when the file has some data it should do what is specified in else.

```
File fileChecker = new File("roomChecker.ser");
if(!fileChecker.exists()) {
    try {
        fileChecker.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Unable to create new File");
    }
}

try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("roomChecker.ser"); ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
    roomFeed = (List<roomChecker>) ois.readObject();
    System.out.println("End of read");
    if(roomFeed.size() == 0) {
        System.out.println("your in null if statement");
        defaultRoomList();
        uploadAvailableRooms();
    } else {
        for(int i=0; i<roomNumber.size(); i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<roomFeed.size(); i++) {
                if((roomNumber.get(i)).equals(roomFeed.get(i).getRoomNumSearch())){
                    System.out.println("Reach Dead End for now");
                } else {
                    defaultRoomList();
                    uploadAvailableRooms();
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: when you create the file the first time, write an empty list to it.

Comment: fileChecker.length() return 0 then file is empty else return > 0 file is not empty two if then send the appropriate methods for each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this:

```
if(!fileChecker.exists()) {
    try {
        fileChecker.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Unable to create new File");
    }
}
```

is a complete waste of time, and it is one of two possible causes for your empty file problem. Creating a file just so you can open it and then get a different problem instead of coping correctly with the original problem of the file not being there isn't a rational strategy. Instead, you should do this:

```
if (fileChecker.isFile() && fileChecker.length() == 0) {
    // file is zero length: bail out
}
```

and, in the following code, this:

```
try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileChecker); ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
    // ...
}
catch (FileNotFoundException exc) {
    // no such file ...
}
// other catch blocks as before.
```

Of course you can still get `EOFException` if you read the file to its end, or if the file is incomplete, and you still need to handle that.

Comment: Sorry... to keep you waiting for the answer approval, as I had other code to wrap up before, to see if your logic works... but yes it indeed work ..What i did was put default conditions in first if block where you check file with the length condition and then put try/catch clause in else condition ...

Comment: And no worries about EOFException it didn't showed up after I corrected my code from your logic..I guess It always shows up if the file was empty and the class thinks it might have reached the end of file unexpectedly.. once the file has some data inside it, it won't throw an EOFException as it had finished reading from the file itself.. Thanks again for you help

Comment: You still have to consider the case where the file is incomplete.